# Detect bad network connectivity on android

Tags: android, api, http, networking

I am building an android app that exchanges data with our server through http api calls. In many cases users are complaining that the app is slow or doesn't work at all.

The most common cause of that is bad network connectivity (low 3g/wifi signal or congested public wifi).

What is the best way to detect bad connections? Once i can detect bad connectivity an icon or toast message can be used to inform the user about the situation.

I am using HttpUrlConnection for the api calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use latency.  Save the time when you get the request, and when the request finishes.  If you're seeing numbers that are too high, pop up the warning.  If you're downloading large files, you may wish to switch to throughput (how many kbps you're transfering).

Comment: The api calls have small payload in general so i should use latency. My problem here is how to distinguish between a bad connection and a slow server response.

Comment: Have the server embed the time it takes to process the request and subtract that from the time?

Comment: Is there a way to get the time until the connection is established?

Comment: I think i will measure the latency using a "ping" api call. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I think you can make use of [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html). Call getActiveNetworkInfo() and then call getDetailedState() on the [NetworkInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html) object received. You can check the state of the connection and whether it is VERIFYING_POOR_LINK, though I don't know in which conditions this state is active.

Also you might want to listen to network changes as described in [Detect Connection Changes](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html#detect-changes).

Comment: this solution is good in the case u want to check if weather you are connected, but no in detecting is the connection is sufficient in heavy tasks or no, I do have a very poor connection indeed but it gives false when VERIFYING_POOR_LINK, and gives true when asking for CONNECTED

Answer (score 1):

as far as i remember http is "connectionless"..

you should try concentrating on minimizing the size of your traffic.. (compress, divide.. etc)

if you really want to test connectivity i guess you should do pings.. every x seconds.. then if the ping is bad you could warn the user..

Comment: Yes http is connectionless (although there is http1.1 where the connection stays open for more than 1 request). I was refering to the device's connectivity.